# How to detrmine the control that cause ContextMenuStrip

Tags: .net, winforms

I am very new to .NET and I had to write a program in which there is a TreeView with different kind of nodes, Each kind of node has a different ContextMenuStrip, So I create multiple kind of ContextMenuStrip and assign then to different kind of TreeNode. Now my question is, when user show a context menu how should I find which TreeNode was the node that cause ContextMenuStrip to show. I try to use `ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl` but it return a TreeView and it never help me, because I know that my source is TreeView I want to know which node of the view! Now should I use some kind of hit test? and if yes what about ContextMenu that shown using keyboard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ContextMenuStrip.Owner Property null When Retrieving From Nested ToolStripMenuItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094528/contextmenustrip-owner-property-null-when-retrieving-from-nested-toolstripmenuit)

Comment: How is it related to that question?? did you ever read the question? I want to find a node that caused the instantiation of the menu. How is it related to finding a menu from its items????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Tag property to "link" the source nodes.
For example, in your form's Load event handler:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode rootNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];        

        rootNode.Nodes[0].ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
        contextMenuStrip1.Tag = rootNode.Nodes[0];

        rootNode.Nodes[1].ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip2;
        contextMenuStrip2.Tag = rootNode.Nodes[1];
    }
```

Then you can bind all ContextMenuStrip controls' Opened event handlers to one method, as below:

```
    private void contextMenuStrip_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip cms = sender as ContextMenuStrip;
        TreeNode aNode = cms.Tag as TreeNode;
        if (aNode != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(aNode.Text);
        }
    }
```

There might be better ways to do it, but I think this should be able to solve your problem.

Updated 2012-10-17:

```
    private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Tag = e.Node;
        }
    }

    private void contextMenuStrip1_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip cms = sender as ContextMenuStrip;
        TreeNode aNode = cms.Tag as TreeNode;
        if (aNode == null)
        {
            aNode = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(aNode.Text);
    }

    private void contextMenuStrip1_Closed(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip cms = sender as ContextMenuStrip;
        cms.Tag = null;
    }
```

Comment: In this way an according to your code I should use a dozen of ContextMenuStrip for a dozen of nodes!! But I only have on ContextMenuStrip per type of node and that's the source of problem

Comment: I don't see where is the difference between one and multiple ContextMenuStrip controls. With the same method that uses Tag property, you should have enough control for the event source. Or maybe I missed something. If you would show some code, I might know where is the problem.

Comment: When you have multiple ContextMenuStrip you can set `Tag` property for each ContextMenuStrip to an specific Node, but otherwise, you just have one ContextMenuStrip for many nodes. Now how you should set Tag to appropriate node??

Comment: I see what you mean. I have also read the comments from Hans Passant and you. I already update my answer. Please see if the new code solved your problem (the user should be able to use keyboard and mouse to open the context menu).

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the end user users a keyboard accelerator for an item on the menu (e.g. if you've got the `ShortcutKeys` property set on a `ToolStripMenuItem` within the `ContextMenuStrip`)