# SourceControl of ContextMenuStrip DropDownItem returns null

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a ContextMenuStrip in a WinForm project. I have added two item in it at design time- 1) Add Focus and 2) Remove Focus. In runtime I am adding few dropdown items in "Add Focus" item. Problem is, I am getting null when trying to retrieve source control name.

Here is my code:

```
ToolStripDropDownItem dropDownItem = sender as ToolStripDropDownItem;
ToolStripMenuItem mainItem = dropDownItem.OwnerItem as ToolStripMenuItem;
ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip = mainItem.Owner as ContextMenuStrip;
Control control =contextMenuStrip.SourceControl; //getting null here
```

What is the problem in this code? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ContextMenuStrip.Owner Property null When Retrieving From Nested ToolStripMenuItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094528/contextmenustrip-owner-property-null-when-retrieving-from-nested-toolstripmenuit)

Answer (score 1):

The context menu strip must be set as the ContextMenuStrip property of a user control or form :)

Source: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/487557/SourceControlplusofplusContextMenuStripplusDropDow