# How to get Parent control from context menu item - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to access the TAG of the parent control (a dynamic button) of the context menu strip sub item.

In my scenario, No. of buttons added dynamically on a form and a ContextMenuStrip named `CMS` is attached with each dynamic button added.

```
BTN.ContextMenuStrip = CMS
```

here is my context menu strip design

[image]

Tag of the parent button should be return by clicking `All`. But I'm always getting NULL.

Here is my code.

```
Dim child As ToolStripMenuItem = sender 'Sub item (text=All)
Dim parent As ToolStripItem = child.OwnerItem 'Parent Item (text=Check)
Dim CMStrip As ContextMenuStrip = parent.Owner 'Context menu strip
MsgBox(CMS.SourceControl.Text) 'Source control should be button but it's null.
```

[image]

I'm using .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: I answered something very similar quite recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700548/vb-net-get-the-control-that-is-used-to-show-the-contextmenu-strip/37701471#37701471

Comment: @Robin Thanks a lot, So it's a bug. I have tried the alternative method you have suggested and is working fine. +1.